# Como pasar el el contenido de una variable de un if(add) a otra variable de otro if(cargar)?

Tags: jquery

Pasar el contenido de una variable dentro de un if() a otro if(). en jquery
Mi duda es como poder hacer eso, aqui les dejo un poco de codigo para hacer mas clara mi pregunta.

```
(function ($) {

this.each(function () {
var easyTree = $(this);
 //desde aqui comienza el problema -************

  if (options.addable) {
      $(createInput).find('.confirm').click(function () {                       
                    if ($(createInput).find('input').val() === '')
                     return;
     // AQUI es donde uso el texto input de entrada y lo pongo en una variable
     var input= $(createInput).find('input').val();
});

    if(options.load){
// ahora yo quiero usar el contenido de esa variable en esta nueva condicion 
//pero no se como llamar a la variable 'input' y a su contenido

         }
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: declara input a mismo nivel de easytree

Comment: supongo que solo lo pongo asi

Comment: var input; y nada mas no?

Comment: asi es... intenta y nos comentas

Comment: pero si hago eso el contenido de eso podre visualizarlo desde cualquier if() que llegue a crear?

Comment: asi es amig@   si entra en el primer if tendra el valor deseado y sino sera indefinido

Comment: como podria usar el contenido de la variable del if(options.addable) en el if(options.load)? o como podria llamarlo para usar su contenido?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es declarar tu variable input como una variable global y no local, es decir:

```
(function ($) {

var input;

this.each(function () {
var easyTree = $(this);
 //desde aqui comienza el problema -************

  if (options.addable) {
      $(createInput).find('.confirm').click(function () {                       
                    if ($(createInput).find('input').val() === '')
                     return;
     // AQUI es donde uso el texto input de entrada y lo pongo en una variable
     input= $(createInput).find('input').val();
});

    if(options.load){
// ahora yo quiero usar el contenido de esa variable en esta nueva condicion 
//pero no se como llamar a la variable 'input' y a su contenido

         }
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: si ya lo hice pero ahora le puse un console.log(input) ; en mi if(options.load) para ver el contenido de esa variable si esta pasando tambien por ahi pero me sale 'undefined', como tendria que hacer para llamar el contenido de ese input en la condicion if(options.load) solo para ver que esta rescatando el dato?

Comment: Aunque como variable global puede salir del bache, creo que lo más acertado es que la variable sea local a la función, inicializada por ejemplo tras easyTree, para que sea visible para todos los if de la función, pero no para elementos externos.

Comment: @Lun Si te da undefined probablemente sea porque no ha entrado en el primer if, que es donde se le da un valor a la variable input. Inicializa input a comillas vacías: var input = ''

Comment: haber, ya lo cambie, es q en el if (options.addable) crea un texto que se muestra en la pagina qeb que estoy desarrolando y eso esta bien hasta ahi, pero quisiera poder usar el condenido de ese if para usarlo en esa otra condicion de if(options.load) , como mas o menos haria?

Comment: @JoseFranciscoDominguezPalac tienes razón podría ser mas acertado, Lun no debería de sacarte undefined puesto que la estás declarando globalmente, otra pregunta, por que tienes el segundo if fuera del each?

Comment: aaaah error de copiar n.n jejeje esta dentro del each los if toditos

Comment: ya no me esta saliendo el undefined , por que elimine una variable gracias , estuvo bien tu comentario, me sirvio para guiarme

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta te invito a que consideres como aceptada para mejorar la experiencia de los próximos desarrolladores que tengan una duda similar, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Debes saber que javascript es asincrono y es orientado a Eventos. te digo esto porque parece que no lo tienes en cuenta cuando escribes tu código.
Te explico:

```
        (function ($) {
var input;
        // Por qué haces esto? no entiendo por qué intentas recorrer todo el doom?
        this.each(function () {
        var easyTree = $(this);
        // Aquí validas que la condición se cumpla, esto es correcto.
          if (options.addable) {
              // aquí defines el evento "clic" a un elemnto, esto quiere decir que se ejecuta unicamente cuando se haga clic sobre el elemento.
              $(createInput).find('.confirm').click(function () {                       
                            if ($(createInput).find('input').val() === '')
                             return;
             // Aquí defines una nueva variable con el valor de un elemento "input", 
             //pero recuerda que esto sucede solo cuando alguien ejecute el evento, es decir, cuando alguien haga clic en el elemento "$(createInput).find('.confirm')"
             input= $(createInput).find('input').val();
        });

            if(options.load){
                    // Aqui no puede usar la variable, porque cuando este código se ejecute, (seguramente es al cargar la pagina) nadie ha hecho click en el elemento, y aún no se ha definido.

                 }
          })(jQuery);
```

Lo que debes hacer es acceder al elemento justo cuando se lance el evento así:

```
(function ($) {
var input;
//Esto lo voy a dejar, pero insisto que no entiendo la razón.
this.each(function () {
var easyTree = $(this);

  if (options.addable) {
      $(createInput).find('.confirm').click(function () {                       
                    if ($(createInput).find('input').val() === '')
                     return;
     // AQUI es donde uso el texto input de entrada y lo pongo en una variable
     var input= $(createInput).find('input').val();
     if(options.load){
            //Aquí ya puedes acceder a la variable :)
         }
});

  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: aaah bueno es q el codigo original es sumamente largo y esto es algo corto que puse como un ejemplo mas o menos, y lo que trato de hacer es un arbol de archivos, cuando creo un texto en el input , este es enviado a ser mostrado por pantalla, y pues se convierte en una carpeta, solo que queria almacenar lo que eran esos inputs de salida, y ya me fije un poco de lo que me hablaron de javascript, y jquery, y estaba omitiendo algunas cosas en mi codigo, pero bueno tambien me sirvio de referencia lo que mencionaste.